# Kendo Sortable events in AngularJS, how to catch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using this Kendo UI component

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/events

with AngularJS and i would like to get index position after end event.

I tried it by thos way:

```
<tbody class="playlist" kendo-sortable k-placeholder="placeholder" k-hint="hint" k-end="testme()">
```

But it does not work.

Could somebody tell me how to do it right with using AngularJS or should i use standart initialization like in example (pure jquery) ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working like this:

Template:

```
<ul kendo-sortable k-options="sortableOptions">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('app').controller('sortableController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        change: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        hint: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        end: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Kendo documentation

> It is possible to specify event handlers using attributes as well. They require the k-on- prefix:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#event-handlers

So it should work if you change your attribute to

```
<tbody ... k-on-end="testme()" >
```